# Select default type of file to be downloaded

Tags: html, .htaccess, file, types

I uploaded a .vtt file on my website, I can access it via the website (http://temporarysubs.8u.cz/subtitles.vtt),

but when I right click and press Save as.. , the default option is "Save as subtitles.txt   instead of subtitles.vtt

Can someone help me change the default file type of my page please?

Comment: Have you set the vtt MIME type in your .htaccess?

Comment: I KNEW it would be something with htaccess :D However, im a complete newbie and they havent tought us about htaccess so i have No idea how to do this. Could you give me a clue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the vtt MIME type to your .htaccess file:

```
AddType text/vtt .vtt
```